# Ошибка в find_element в selenium

Tags: python, selenium

При запуске функции

```
def run(driver_path):    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)    
    driver.get('https://tproger.ru/quiz/real-programmer/')    
    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("quiz_button")
    button.click()
run(driver_path)
```

выдаёт ошибку

```
<ipython-input-27-c5a7960e105f>:6: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
<ipython-input-27-c5a7960e105f>:10: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("quiz_button")
```

открывается в окне браузер и через пол секунды закрывается. Хотя `driver.close() driver.quit()` не прописано.
в предлагаемых решениях инета было импортировать дополнительно `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC, from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By, from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait`. Не помогло

Comment: Это не ошибка, а предупреждение. Даже два разных. Нужно их прочитать и сделать выводы. Закрывается наверняка по какой-то другой причине.

Comment: @Эникейщик вебдрайвер скачан последней версии от 28.10. для моей версии браузера. И не совсем понятно как устарел find_element_by_* устарел, если в документации они есть и не сказано, что устарело